# C dll from mingw in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dll, mingw

I want to call a function from a C dll. This dll was created by compiling on ubuntu/mingw. I want to use this dll functions in C#. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a managed signature using the [`[DllImport]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) attribute and then P/Invoke into the unmanaged library. Example from MSDN calling the [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx) function from `user32.dll`:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Example
{
    // Use DllImport to import the Win32 MessageBox function.
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);

    static void Main()
    {
        // Call the MessageBox function using platform invoke.
        MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Hello World!", "Hello Dialog", 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Add the DLL as a project resource
2. Add the Using statement to associate the dll
3. code away.

See Also: [Adding a dll file to a C# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029556/adding-a-dll-file-to-a-c-project)