# passing array between two C# Windows Form application

Tags: c#

I have two C# application and I want interactive them by calling one program 
giveMeDataArray(xIndex,yIndex)
and then second program send response to first program by sending an array to it
please help me on this issue....
thnx

**EDIT**: I have a program that generate numbers and a program show that.
when user scroll in presentation program, that request for data. this data provided by second program and type of data is array
i just want have this array in first application

Comment: Just clarifying, you have two applications and you want to have an array of data shared between both?  Or you have two applications that you want to interact with, with one main program?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153/interprocess-communication-for-windows-in-c-net-2-0

Comment: We expect something more specific, you didn't ask anything. What you want know? How to do? Your code base?
Give us some input, please

Comment: You need an interprocess communication mechanism.  A socket, named pipe or WCF.

Comment: I would suggest showing some code that you have tried.  If you can't demonstrate that you have made an attempt at solving the problem, you are not going to get much help.

Answer (score 1):

You should reference one app to another with dll.if you don't know how to add dll you can visit [Adding a dll file to a C# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029556/adding-a-dll-file-to-a-c-project)